# Evaluating math Equations with Brackets

Tags: shell, unix, math, ksh

I am just trying to Convert secs back to hours n minutes for a day.  However am hitting an error in the Minute Equation! its not evaluating the braces in the order! how can we evalvate math equations like the one I have below.

I want to divide the total_secs by 3600 and then multiply the result with 60 then Again find the modulus of the result with 60.

Here s my attempt

```
#!/bin/ksh  
set -x  
total_secs=3685;  
hour=$(( (total_secs % 3600) ));  
minute=$(( (((total_secs / 3600) * 60) % 60) ));  
seconds=$(( (((total_secs / 3600) * (60) * (60)) % 60) ));  
echo ""$hour":"$minute":"$seconds""
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Your example doesn't give any error.  That said, the maths is not quite right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of operations wasn't what was causing the problem. According to [this reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_arith_eval.htm), the Korn shell has the same precedence and associativity as the `C` programming language, so multiplication, division and remainder happen from left to right. The correct maths would be:

```
#!/bin/ksh

total_secs=3685
hour=$(( total_secs / 3600 ))
minute=$(( total_secs / 60 % 60  )) # equivalent to (total_secs / 60) % 60
seconds=$(( total_secs % 60 ))
echo "$hour:$minute:$seconds"
# output 1:1:25
```

If you want to format the output, perhaps you could use `printf`

```
printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $hour $minute $seconds
# output 01:01:25
```

### edit: operator precedence

Basic arithmetic operations are carried out in the following order:

1. `*` `/` `%`
2. `+` `-`

Multiple operations of the *same precedence* will be evaluated from **left to right as they appear in the expression**.

```
$(( ((x*y) / z) + n ))
```

is equivalent to either of the following:

```
$(( x * y / z + n ))
$(( n + x * y / z ))
```

because in both cases, the `*` is the highest precedence and nearest to the left of the expression. Second will be the `/` and finally the `+`.

There is no harm in inserting additional `( )` to make your intentions clear but remember that the whole expression must be enclosed within `$(( ))`.

Comment: THank you!

Could you pls share, how to evaluvate Expressions with More than a single opertion. Like if the Expression s (((x*y)/z)+n) , my order of evaluvation should be x*y follwed by the division of the Result with z and then addition with n

Comment: @Nanda There is more than one operation in the evaluation of `minute`. First the division, then the remainder. They are evaluated one by one from left to right. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Output working but when the total seconds is something like 3667
it says error in printf line says 7 : invalid number!
ie Accordin to calculation 3667 should return 01:01:07 but its not returning the seconds value but the error msg and output is 01:01:00

Comment: @Nanda I just tried with `total_secs=3667` and it worked for me. I can't reproduce that behaviour.

Comment: Error:
printf: 7}: invalid number
01:01:00